# Camel setBody using Spring configuration

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have built a Java Camel Timer-JMS route using:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
   public void configure() {
    from("timer:foo?period=1s").setBody(body().
       append("Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")).to("jms:queue:activemq/queue/TestQueue");
   }
});
```

Now I need to turn it to Spring.

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="timer:foo?period=1s" />
    <camel:to uri="jms:queue:activemq/queue/TestQueue" />
</camel:route>
```

I'm missing the equivalent in Spring XML configuration of the expression:

```
setBody(body().append("Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Spring you can use the simple language, to build such messages. In fact you can also do this in Java, it the same.

```
<setBody>
  <simple>${body}Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</simple>
</setBody>
```

Mind that the timer sends an empty/null body. So you may see "null" in the message.

About simple see: http://camel.apache.org/simple

Comment: Thanks for the Sunday tip! :-)

Comment: @Claus: I am using similar way in camle route xml, but it is not able to find date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814908/how-to-add-date-to-camel-route-xml-to-uri

Comment: How to set body as null? `<setBody><simple/></setBody>`, or does that create empty string?